# if statement exception when a list is modified for a dialogue tree

Tags: python

I'm creating a dialogue tree for a text-adventure game that uses a list to hold the dialogue choices. When a user selects an option from the list, it responds and then removes that option from the list so that users can't select it again. The problem is that once I select one option (the first instance of the loop), the second choice always returns an error.

Here's the code:

```
x = 1
dec1 = '"Why are you doing this? What do you want?"'
dec2 = '"You keep talking about Thread. What is it?"'
dec3 = '"Can you help me?"'
dec4 = 'Say nothing.'
decision = [dec1, dec2, dec3, dec4]

while x == 1:

    for i in decision:
        print '%d. %s' % (decision.index(i) + 1, i)

    current_input = input.return_input(charstate)

    if isinstance(current_input, int):
        if int(current_input) > len(decision) or int(current_input) < 1:
            print '\n"I don\'t understand, %s."' % charstate.charname
            continue
        elif int(current_input) == decision.index(dec1) + 1:
            print 'text'
            decision.remove(dec1)
        elif int(current_input) == decision.index(dec2) + 1:
            print 'text'
            decision.remove(dec2)
        elif int(current_input) == decision.index(dec3) + 1:
            print 'text'
            decision.remove(dec3)
        elif int(current_input) == 4:
            print 'text'
            x += 1
        else:
            exit(1)
    else:
        print '\n"I don\'t understand, %s."' % charstate.charname
        continue
```

The problem appears to be that after I select one option, the if conditional returns an error because decision.index(dec#) no longer exists. At least, that's what I've been able to figure out. The specific error is "ValueError: x is not in list". I'm trying to figure out a way to set it up so that that doesn't happen.

The only idea I've had is creating separate try...except statements for each of the choices, which seems incredibly inelegant and bloated. There has to be something simple that I'm missing.

Thanks everyone!

edit: input.return_input(charstate) is a function that just returns a raw_input. "charstate" is an object that holds the current character information and choice history--it's passed between events and scenes.

Comment: what is  `current_input = input.return_input(charstate)`?

Comment: Ah, good catch. Forgot to explain. input.return_input(charstate) is a method/function that gets a raw_input from the user. It's farmed out to its own class because it checks against certain global commands like 'help'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I actually figured out how to do what I needed to do. pseudonym's answer was a good first step for me, but then I realized I needed to actually run separate code depending on the answer, not just print something different.

I've restructured the code so that I don't need to call an index to identify which answer was chosen. It was actually a relatively simple fix, once I got my head around it.

```
    dec1 = '"Why are you doing this? What do you want?"'
    dec2 = '"You keep talking about Thread. What is it?"'
    dec3 = '"Can you help me?"'
    dec4 = 'Say nothing.'
    decision = [dec1, dec2, dec3, dec4]

    while True:

        for i in decision:
            print '%d. %s' % (decision.index(i) + 1, i)

        current_input = input.return_input(charstate)

        if isinstance(current_input, int):

            current_input = int(current_input)

            if current_input - 1 in xrange(0, len(decision)):
                response = decision[current_input - 1]
            elif current_input - 1 not in xrange(0, len(decision)):
                print '\n"I don\'t understand, %s."\n' % charstate.charname
                continue
            else:
                exit(1)
        else:
            print '\n"I don\'t understand, %s."\n' % charstate.charname
            continue

        if response == dec1:
            print 'dec1'
        elif response == dec2:
            print 'dec2'
        elif response == dec3:
            print 'dec3'
        elif response == dec4:
            print 'dec4'
            break
        else:
            exit(1)

        del decision[current_input - 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete from the array by the index instead, i believe this will give you the functionality your looking for

```
dec1 = '"Why are you doing this? What do you want?"'
dec2 = '"You keep talking about Thread. What is it?"'
dec3 = '"Can you help me?"'
dec4 = 'Say nothing.'
decision = [[dec1,'text1'], [dec2,'text2'], [dec3,'text3'], [dec4,'text4']]

while True:

    for i in decision:
        print '%d. %s' % (decision.index(i) + 1, i[0])

    current_input = input.return_input(charstate)

    if isinstance(current_input, int):
        if int(current_input) > len(decision) or int(current_input) < 1:
            print '\n"I don\'t understand, %s."' % charstate.charname
            continue
        elif int(current_input) in xrange(1,len(decision)):
            print '%s' % (decision[int(current_input)-1][1])
            del decision[int(current_input)-1]
        elif int(current_input) == 4:
            print 'text'
            break
        else:
            exit(1)
    else:
        print '\n"I don\'t understand, %s."' % charstate.charname
        continue
```

Comment: The way you have this set up does fix the error message, but seems to remove the ability to create different outcomes based on the input.

Comment: sorry about that, edited the code. Notice the three different lines, the decision array declaration is now a 2d array, the answer for dec1 is text1, etc; the print within the for loop has a i[0] now; and the elif statement's print call has changed. Hope this works for you

Comment: You're a god. Maybe a smallish god, but still. Thanks a lot--this make total sense to me now that you've shown me, and it seems to work perfectly.

Comment: I actually realized that I need more than this offers me--I need to run code separately depending on the answer. I figured out how to fix my original problem in a separate answer. Thanks again for the help.